# Como criar uma janela de confirmação em um sistema em PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Sou iniciante na programação e estou criando um pequeno sistema e nele eu terei um botão de deslogar o usuário, o código:

```
<a href="../controller/controller.deslogar.php" title="Deslogar"><img src="img/logout.png" class="icon2"></a>
```

Como vocês devem ter percebido, ao clicar na imagem, o usuário é automaticamente deslogado, porém eu gostaria de colocar uma janela de confirmação antes de deslogar o usuário, porque as vezes ele pode ter clicado sem querer. Gostaria que na janela de confirmação, tivesse 2 botões, "OK" e "Cancelar", caso o usuario clicasse no botão "OK", ele seria deslogado, se ele clicasse em "Cancelar", apenas fecharia a janela de confirmação.

Procurei na internet, mas não achei exatamente o que eu queria e como sou iniciante, não consigo criar do 0 isso.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Será que é isto que quer?

```
<a href="../controller/controller.deslogar.php" onclick="return confirm(Quer deslogar?');" title="Deslogar"><img src="img/logout.png" class="icon2"></a>
```

**Também pode ser feito da seguinte forma:**

```
var logout = confirm("Quer fazer logout?");

if(logout){
     location.href = "../controller/controller.deslogar.php";
}
```

Comment: Exatamente isso! O unico problema é quando eu dou F5 já aparece a janela de confirmação, ela deveria aparecer apenas quando eu clicar no botão deslogar.

Comment: @GabrielQueiroz Aparece porque o F5 sozinho não actualiza o Javascript, terá de fazer crtl + F5 para actualizar página completa

Answer (score 0):

Tente com JQuery:

```
$('a[title="Deslogar"]').click(function(){
    confirm('Quer fazer logout?');
});
```